# Small Amount of Text at Bottom of Last Column of First page

Tags: positioning, memoir, two-column

I'm trying to create a document that emulates the style of the *Journal of the American Chemical Society*. At the bottom of the first page, they have a small "footer" with the received and published dates like so:
[image]

This isn't part of the footer; it sits at the bottom of the second column. The text above it flows onto the top of the next page as normal.

How would I go about creating a text area like this in a two-column layout with the `memoir` class?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum

\textbf{Some text:} To go at the bottom
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the *small amount of text* to be part of the text, you can put it into the footnote.  I don't use `memoir`, maybe it provides a better way to do this.  You can locally redefine `\@makefntext` and use `\footnotetext`.  Code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,array,atbegshi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\received[1]{%
  \def\receiv@d{#1}%
}

\newcommand\published[1]{%
  \def\publish@d{#1}%
}

\let\SavedFootnoterule\footnoterule
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\global\let\footnoterule\SavedFootnoterule}

\newcommand\receivedpublished{%
  \def\footnoterule{%
    \kern-3\p@
    {\color{blue}\hrule \@height .6pt \@width\columnwidth}%
    \kern2.4\p@
  }%
  \begingroup
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{%
      \parindent \z@
      \noindent
      ##1}%
    \footnotetext{%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries\color{blue}}l@{ }l}
        Received:  & \receiv@d \\
        Published: & \publish@d
      \end{tabular}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\received{October 19, 2016}
\published{February 20, 2017}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]

\receivedpublished

\clearpage

Restore\footnote{Original footnoterule}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Of course footnotes are still the answer! `memoir` does provide some macros and lengths to avoid some of the `@` issues, but it's a fairly simple translation from your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `tikz` and `atbegshi` in this case like below; you can change the origins.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, article]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
    \node [anchor=east] at ($(current page.south east) + (-30mm,10mm)$) 
{\textbf{Some text:} To go at the bottom };

\end{tikzpicture}
}}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works if I wanted the text outside the main text block. If I move the positioning into the text block, it overlays the text instead of allowing it to flow, which makes sense given the options used. I'll keep this in mind for slightly different situations, though!